# Storing a input into a tree

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I want to store the following input in a tree such that a number (lets call it x) at level i has two children at level i+1, one is just below x and the other one is one position right to the node just below x. For example, consider the following input:

1

2 1

3 1 3

4 2 1 1

Here the number 1 at level 2 (level starts from 0) has two children 2 and 1.

I want to store it in a tree. How to do this?

Comment: which language? please tag your question with some popular, language related tags so that your question gets more attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your question is not very specific:
you might want to read the wiki article about [binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) an then update your question in a more precise way?